# How to implement Bubble Chart / Circle Packing in React Native?

Tags: react-native, d3.js, bubble-chart, circle-pack

I want to render a Bubble Chart (Circle Packing) dynamic with an data array as a prop in React Native using EXPO (no native code). I wonder which way I could go to implement this chart. Do I use d3? And if yes, does it work for React Native? Are there other ideas on how to implement this bubble chart? Does it work only with SVG? Or d3 including SVG?

I found also a [react library](https://github.com/weknowinc/react-bubble-chart-d3) that renders the Bubble Chart like in the picture below but the styles and other attributes from react aren't matching to React Native.

I have not yet found an answer to this problem. Does anyone in the community encounter this problem and solved it?

[image: Example of Circle Packing / Bubble Chart]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-chart-wrapper](https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper) as it is providing bubble chart with a list of additional charts

Comment: I just saw the library and it uses native code that won't work if you are working with expo. I edited my question above because I use expo.